# What is a "nonzero equation"?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Does it mean that there is at least one non-zero coefficient?  That the solution set does not include the zero vector?  That the the equation is non-homogenous?  I am asking because the phrase is used in my linear algebra text (Friedberg, Insel, Spence.)

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: It would really help to know the context. Can you give an example of this usage?

Comment: Can you give the complete sentence that includes the phrase "nonzero equation"?

Comment: I guess that it is being used to *non zero linear combination*.

Comment: If you have the text, it is in Theorem 3.15 (p. 189).  The truth is that I don't accept the theorem.  It states: that

"Let Ax = b be a system of r nonzero equations in n unknowns.  Suppose that rank(A) = rank(A|b) and that (A|b) is in RR-echelon form. Then

a) rank(A) = r."

This is the part I don't accept.  Couldn't you simply have two repeated rows in Ax = b? Then there would clearly be strictly less than r linearly independent rows in RR-echelon form.

Comment: I think it just means that $B$ is not zero.  But not sure.

Comment: @John Machop: What's your definition of reduced row-echelon form...? :)

Comment: Any ideas on how to make sense of either this phrase or the theorem itself?  It just doesn't seem correct to me, regardless of what "nonzero equation" means.

Comment: The definition is on p.185 of the same text.  If whoever posted the last picture (thank you, by the way) could post the definition as well, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @John: I think I have a different edition of the book than you do, but hopefully this is what you're after.

Comment: Yes, we do seem to have different editions.  But you posted exactly the right thing -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In row echelon form, the rank is exactly the number of nozero rows. Therefore (a) indicateds that "nonzero equation" is one where at least one coefficient (or the right hand side) is nonzero. Note that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A|B)$ implies that there are no contradictory equations.

Comment: But what about repeated equations?  For example, consider

x + 2y = 3
w + 2z = 3.

The rank of both the augmented matrix and matrix of coefficients is one, but there are two equations.  So how can we say that the rank of the coefficient matrix is equal to the number of equations?

Comment: Repeated (nonzero) equations are excluded by the row echelon form

Comment: My point exactly.  But it doesn't say that A is in row echelon form in the equation Ax = b.  Therefore it could have repeated equations; thus, the rank would be less than the number of equations.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that we don't simplify (A|b) into RR-echelon form, but it is already in RR-echelon form. That is, the matrix A here is a special matrix where A|b becomes RR-echelon form without any elementary row operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of sloppy formulation, as can already be seen from the given definition, which clearly describes (because of condition (b)) a *reduced* row echelon form, not a general row echelon form as it claims. But for what is meant by nonzero (linear) equation, there should be no ambiguity: linear equations (in a given set of unknowns, over a given field) form a vector space (one can add them and multiply them by scalars) and any nonzero vector in this space of equations is a nonzero equation.

The given theorem is true, but badly formulated nonetheless. I would make the statement clearer and more general by changing the hypothesis to

> **Theorem 3.15.** *Let $AX=B$ be a system of linear equations in $n$ unknowns (forming the unknown column$~X$) with $A$ in row echelon form, and $\def\rk{\operatorname{rank}}\rk(A)=\rk(A\mid b)$; let $m$ be the number of nonzero rows of $A$.*

In particular, it is not necessary to have a reduced row echelon form for the conclusions to hold, nor to remove zero equations from the system (as long as $m$ does not count them); the condition $\rk(A)=\rk(A\mid B)$ ensures that any nonzero equation corresponds to a nonzero row of $A$.

In point (b) of the conclusion is mainly that the solution space $\ker(A)$ of the homogeneous system $AX=0$ has dimension $n-m$ and that every solution $X=s$ of $AX=B$ can be uniquely written as $s=s_0+v$ with $s_0$ a fixed chosen solution, and $v\in\ker(A)$. Presumably $s_0$ and a $n-m$-element generating family $[u_1,\ldots,u_{n-m}]$ of $\ker(A)$ are mechanically produced from the form of the reduced system $AX=B$ in the preceding text.