# Theorem 3.15 Linear Algebra Friedberg, Insel and Spence how is my counterexample wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, matrix-equations, alternative-proof

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$
Part (a) of Theorem 3.15 is: let $Ax=b$ be a system of $r$ nonzero equations in $n$ unknowns. Suppose that $\rank{A}=\rank{A|b}$ and that $(A|b)$ is in reduced echelon form. Then: $\rank{A}=r$

I believe that **nonzero** means each row contains a nonzero entry.

The following definition of **reduced echelon form** is provided in the book:

a) any row containing a nonzero entry precedes any row in which all entries are zero

b) the first nonzero entry in each row is the only nonzero entry in it's column

c) The first nonzero entry in each row is 1 and it occurs in a column to the right of the first nonzero entry in the preceding row

A post which (has a similar issue to me, if not the same issue) [was made in 2013](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448925/what-is-a-nonzero-equation). But to me it seems it never recieved an answer that addressed the posters issue with the Theorem.

My issue with this is: consider a matrix which has an equation that is a multiple of the other, but still has a nomempty solution set for $b$, this does not satisfy the first line of the proof which states "since $(A|b)$ is in reduced echelon form, $(A|b)$ must have $r$ nonzero rows."

Consider the following counterexample I've come up with. If I am somehow ignoring a restriction of the theorem please let me know.

$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 7 & 8 \\
2 & 14 & 16 \\
3 & 1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and
$$
b=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
(A|b)=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{20} & 1 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{23}{20} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Clearly $\rank{A}=\rank{A|b}$ (just by looking at the span of the rows or columns). But $\rank{A}\neq3=r$, contradicting Theorem 3.15.

Comment: Re "My issue with this is: consider a matrix which has an equation that is a multiple of the other": if that happens, then certainly the first non-zero entry in one of these rows is not the only non-zero entry in its column, nor does that entry in the lower row come to the right of the corresponding entry in the higher row. In other words the hypothesis excludes this case. (By the way what you have described is a _reduced_ row echelon form. )

Comment: And you seem to be confused about matrix equality. A matrix is (in general) not equal to its reduced echelon form, so you cannot call both the original matrix and the echelon form $A$. In the theorem, the matrix is _already_ reduced, there is no original unreduced matrix in the statement.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I am talking about $A$, not $(A|b)$ The theorem says $(A|b)$ is in reduced echelon form, not $A$. 
So there being a row that is a multiple of the other in $A$ is fine, and it doesn't contradict the premises of the theorem, since $A$ just has to be a matrix such that the rank of $A$ is equivalent to $(A|b)$ where $(A|b)$ is in row echelon form.
Can you please tell me how exactly the counterexample I have provided does not contradict the theorem?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Where did I call both $A$ and its reduced echelon form both $A$? I alreday know you cant do that, and dont know where you're saying I did. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your comment a few above is wrong. If $(A|b)$ is in reduced echelon form, then necessarily $A$ is as well. There cannot be a pivot in the augmented column ($b$); if there were, we would have $\text{rank}(A|b) = \text{rank}(A)+1$. Note that $(A|b)$ is assumed to be in reduced echelon form and the equations are assumed to be nonzero. So this is why the rank must be $r$.

Comment: "Since $A$ just has to be a matrix such that the rank of $A$ is equivalent to $(A|b)$ where $(A|b)$ is in row echelon form." No, the theorem requires $A$ to be a matrix whose rank is equal to the rank of $(A|b)$, **and** for $(A|b)$ to **be** in row echelon, not for you to manipulate $(A|b)$  to put it *into* row echelon form.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $(A|b)$ in the book is in Section 3.2, under **Inverse of a Matrix**, on Page 160 in the 5th Edition:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $m\times n$ and $m\times p$ matrices, respectively. By the **augmented matrix** $(A|B)$ we mean the $m\times (n+p)$ matrix $(A\ B)$, that is, the matrix whose first $n$ columns are the columns of $A$ and whose last $p$ columns are the columns of $b$.

If $A$ and $b$ are
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&7&8\\ 2&14&16\\ 3&1&1\end{array}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad b=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 2\\ 3\end{array}\right),$$
then $(A|b)$ is the $3\times 4$ matrix whose first three columns are the columns of $A$, and whose fourth column is the (unique) column of $B$. That is,
$$(A|b) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&7&8&1\\
2&14&16&2\\
3&1&1&3
\end{array}\right).$$
This matrix is not in reduced row echelon form, so the theorem does not apply to this system/matrix $A$ and vector $b$.

Note the hypothesis of the Theorem has two clauses:

1. $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ must equal $\mathrm{rank}(A|b)$; and
2. $(A|b)$ must be in reduced row echelon form.

These two conditions must be met with the given $A$ and $b$.

What you have labeled "$(A|b)$" is a matrix obtained from $(A|b)$ through Gaussian elimination to put it into reduced row echelon form, but is not in fact the matrix $(A|b)$ that the Theorem is talking about.

Note that the theorem doesn't talk about *reducing* $(A|b)$ into reduced row echelon form; it doesn't say "the reduced row echelon form of $(A|b)$", it doesn't tell you to *put* $(A|b)$ *into* reduced row echelon form. It requires that $(A|b)$ **already** be in reduced row echelon form, with $A$ and $b$ *as is*.

Comment: The last paragraph is what I needed to understand thank you lots!